# how to make a binary heat map several times on a data frame

Tags: r, plot

I have a data looks like below

```
df<- structure(list(time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
), grp = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A","B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), `02` = c(36034L, 63763L, 
51432L, 65100L, 61444L, 71012L, 266610L, 389787L, 47659L, 63156L, 
84593L, 84331L, 514204L, 685995L, 325569L, 394893L, 88586L, 119206L
), `03` = c(45632L, 66505L, 60360L, 36685L, 107551L, 53360L, 
323952L, 344944L, 69601L, 51268L, 130665L, 59704L, 541017L, 578627L, 
424918L, 336442L, 156380L, 80952L), `04` = c(59025L, 52837L, 
68571L, 35788L, 75262L, 66601L, 424683L, 340948L, 79487L, 42809L, 
95607L, 81739L, 729858L, 606794L, 501805L, 333508L, 112263L, 
112676L), `05` = c(74767L, 48210L, 70972L, 67705L, 85576L, 89265L, 
393380L, 306633L, 77816L, 73611L, 106317L, 116890L, 677483L, 
533762L, 375046L, 483442L, 136605L, 160272L), `06` = c(50846L, 
37970L, 63896L, 78296L, 81216L, 62308L, 62613L, 21770L, 80955L, 
88832L, 97586L, 68345L, 100610L, 38642L, 130879L, 134422L, 164913L, 
112949L), `07` = c(26688L, 27830L, 17010L, 54074L, 26727L, 31109L, 
24448L, 38701L, 17378L, 46327L, 25324L, 25325L, 22457L, 33676L, 
20154L, 33916L, 25483L, 24284L), `08` = c(16498L, 26604L, 41201L, 
38417L, 43709L, 33217L, 69943L, 80638L, 37444L, 31701L, 46781L, 
31152L, 69223L, 102067L, 47771L, 70210L, 44783L, 22790L), `09` = c(16272L, 
24485L, 14546L, 74756L, 28193L, 770L, 72238L, 78418L, 9161L, 
48618L, 26466L, 1078L, 67369L, 89824L, 37838L, 93295L, 20890L, 
998L), `10` = c(20612L, 713L, 18114L, 57872L, 25684L, 27985L, 
73618L, 1770L, 11953L, 33347L, 25824L, 25860L, 70949L, 1520L, 
46044L, 66312L, 20971L, 20217L), `11` = c(23549L, 856L, 32854L, 
42906L, 33385L, 26218L, 88509L, 62103L, 23377L, 29738L, 33504L, 
26642L, 104893L, 100707L, 53324L, 63296L, 24867L, 21114L)), .Names = c("time", 
"grp", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
"11"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 18L))
```

I want to make a binary heatmap 3 times on this data.

There are A to F at time 1, A to F at time 5 and A to F at time 12

I want to get the range between the smallest and the highest for each time set and then make a binary coloring something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want your plot to look like - it seems to me that you have both the grp and the various numbers (participant IDs?) as potential x-axis variables.  And are the y-axis marks the mean value?

Regardless, I've got your data set up a bit for plotting:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
test <- melt(df, id = c("time", "grp"), variable.name = "Participant", 
                                        value.name = "Score")

test2 <- spread(test, key = time, value = Score)
colnames(test2) <- c("Group", "Participant", "T1", "T5", "T12")
```

From this point, you can do something like:

```
ggplot(test2) + geom_tile(aes(x = Group, y = Participant, fill = T1))
```

It's not exactly what you want, but I'm a little confused about what is going where on your plot.  That'll get you started on heatmapping, at least

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. Let me try to give you en example about what I am looking for. I just posted a new question which is more straightforward

Comment: the above question, has 3 data sets in it. I want to plot 3 times heat map on the same data (section 1, section 2 and section 3) according to the time

Comment: section one is when the time is 1. we take the minimum and maximum of the matrix and then set it as both extreme (highest color to lowest color) then plot it. Then we do the same for the second 2 and section 3 and we will have 3 plots in one

Comment: Ah, something like a facet_wrap? (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html)

In that case...

    `require(ggplot2)`
    `require(reshape2)`
    `test <- melt(df, id = c("time", "grp"), variable.name = "Participant", 
                                             value.name = "Score")`
    `ggplot(test2) + geom_tile(aes(x = Group, y = Participant, fill = Score)) + 
    facet_wrap(time ~ .)`

Note that you can change this to `facet_wrap(. ~ time)` to switch the direction of wrapping (by row vs. by column)

Comment: Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Comment: Sorry, messed up a couple of things when switching between threads.  `ggplot() + geom_tile(data = test, aes(x = grp, y = Participant, fill = Score)) + facet_grid(time ~ .)`

Comment: can we change the color ? and also make the `grp`as y axis?

Comment: In the "aes" argument of geom_tile, just swap "grp" and "Participant".  And see the your other thread for a color example