# how to plot a binary with a given range of values

Tags: r, plot

I have asked a question here [how to make a binary heat map several times on a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081191/how-to-make-a-binary-heat-map-several-times-on-a-data-frame) without getting any feedback which I believe it is not that easy. I tried to break down the problem in order to get some answer

so I consider having only one data in my data structure as follows

```
df1<- structure(list(time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), level = structure(1:6, .Label = c("B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), X2 = c(266L, 480L, 
396L, 501L, 481L, 542L), X3 = c(356L, 587L, 491L, 320L, 883L, 
422L), X4 = c(452L, 406L, 521L, 300L, 582L, 506L), X5 = c(549L, 
368L, 548L, 528L, 673L, 701L), X6 = c(414L, 398L, 526L, 593L, 
639L, 484L)), .Names = c("time", "level", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", 
"X6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

at first I get the range of it as follows:

```
min(df1[3:length(df1)])
max(df1[3:length(df1)])
```

it means that the data is distributed between 266 and 883.

now I want to set the one closer to lower to be red and the one closer to higher value to be yellow

I tried to plot it with `reshape2`as follows but I could not figure out how to set the values and other stuff

```
library(reshape2)
melted_cormat <- melt(df1)
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=level, y=variable, fill=value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something similar to your code (note inclusion of "id" variable)...

```
melted_cormat <- melt(df1, id = c("time", "level"))
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=level, y=variable, fill=value)) +
       geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "yellow")
```

made this plot...
[image]

Note that you can substitute hex codes for "red" and "yellow" in scale_fill_gradient, if you want a particular hue or two.

Comment: can you please now help me with the other question ? one more favor and I accept this answer already. if I use `aes(x=variable, y=level, fill=value))` it shows G E F, is there any possibility to reorder it and make it B C D E F ... ?

Comment: `df1$level <- factor(df1$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))`

Comment: does not change anything . please run this `df1$level <- factor(df1$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))
melted_cormat <- melt(df1, id = c("time", "level"))
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=variable, y=level, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "yellow")`

Comment: @nik What are you asking for? When I run that code in your comment the x-axis is B, C, D, E, F, G, just like in this nice answer.

Comment: @Gregor somehow does not change the order but I accepted it

Comment: The order plotted will always be the level order of the factor in the data frame. `df1$level <- factor(df1$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))` explicitly sets that order. Check `levels(melted_cormat$level)` to see your order and make sure you aren't ignoring any error messages or getting different data frames mixed up. You could also set the levels after melting: `melted_cormat$level = factor(melted_cormat$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))`. But my guess is you have several data frames in your workspace and are using a different version.